# Re render flat list when data change cause infinite loop React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I have two screens. **Approve List** and **Approve Detail**. When data approved in Approve Detail, page navigate to Approve List. Then approved data should disapear from FLatList. How to remove FlatList item when data approved? or how to re render FlatList when data change? Here is my code:

Approve List:

```
const Approve = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [rekomendasi, setRekomendasi] = useState({})
 // other code
 const getRekomendasi = async (token, bagian) => {
    try {
        const response = await sippApi.get(`/penjaminan?bagian=${bagian}`, {
            headers: {
                Auth: token
            }
        });
        setRekomendasi(response.data.data)
        console.log(rekomendasi)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
 }
 useEffect(() => {
    getToken();
    getUserData()
    getRekomendasi(token, userData.bagian);
 }, [setToken, setUserData, rekomendasi]); // if I pass rekomendasi here, make infinite loop on api request

 return (
  <FlatList
    onRefresh={() => onRefresh()}
    refreshing={isFetching}
    removeClippedSubviews
    style={{ marginTop: 2 }}
    data={rekomendasi}
    keyExtractor={rekom => rekom.penjaminan.nomor_rekomendasi}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ApproveDetail", { id: item.penjaminan.nomor_rekomendasi, bagian: userData.bagian })}>
            <ApproveList
               plafond={item.value}
               kantor={item.nama_kantor}
               nomor_rekomendasi={item.nomor_rekomendasi}
               produk={item.skim}
              />
         </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      }}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
)
}
```

If I pass value on second argument on UseEffect, it cause infinite loop on API request. If not, my FlatList cant re render when data change. What should I do?

Thanks for help

Comment: which data is changing in the above?

Comment: @GauravRoy rekomendasi

Comment: it should update the flatlist if rekomendasi is updated

Comment: @GauravRoy how to update flatlist if data updated? i tried using extraData but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using useFocusEffect

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        getRekomendasi(token, userData.bagian)
    }, [token, userData.bagian])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the **rekomendasi** **dependency** in the useEffect to avoid infinite loop, it's only for init data :)

What is the purpose of onRefresh function in the FlatList ? Instead you could put the **getRekomendasi** function to trigger a new call and your data will be updated

Comment: onRefresh is for pull to refresh function

Comment: const onRefresh = () => {
        setIsFetching(true);
        getRekomendasi(token, userData.bagian)
        setIsFetching(false)
    }

Comment: if I remove rekomendasi in useEffect, flatList dont re render when data change

Answer (score 0):

try to separate the functions to two useEffects

```
 useEffect(() => {
    //<-- write your getToken() and getUserDate() here 
    getToken();
    getUserData()
 }, []);
 useEffect(() => {
    const getRekomendasi = async (token, bagian) => {
    try {
        const response = await sippApi.get(`/penjaminan?bagian=${bagian}`, {
            headers: {
                Auth: token
            }
        });
        setRekomendasi(response.data.data)
        console.log(rekomendasi)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
 }
 getRekomendasi(token, userData.bagian);

 },[token,userData.bagian]);
```

Comment: this is good idea, but still not work

Comment: is still the same problem ?

Comment: try to add  extraData={rekomendasi} to your flatlist